# How to get a count of number of occurrence of a substring in a string in teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have a column in a teradata table with string values like "page1-->page2-->page1-->page3-->page1--page2-->..."

I want to search for a specific page and get the number of occurrence of the page in the string. I couldn't find any function that gives this result.

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin function, but there's a common solution:

Remove all occurences of the substring from the string and compare the length before/after:

```
(Char_Length(string) - Char_Length(OReplace(string, searchstr))) / Char_Length(searchstr)
```

Edit:

For a wildcard search you can utilize REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
Char_Length(RegExp_Replace(RegExp_Replace(s, 'page1(.+?)page3', '#',1,0), '[^#]','',1,0))
```

For `#' use a character which is known not to be in your input string.

Comment: Is there a way to get the counts if i am using wildcard search using %? For instance when the search string is "page1%page3"

Comment: You could do a similar approach using RegEx, I'll update my anwer.

Comment: Thank yo very much @dnoeth

Comment: @JitheeshVijayan - If this answers your question, be sure to accept the answer.